# Syncing code, project files, across computers without using version control

Tags: version-control, cross-platform, synchronization

Hi
Since I'm always transferring files, primarily plain text for coding, between home and office, I was wonder if other coders would share their preferred method for doing this. Is version control, checking in and out, really the best way to sync remote data, or is there some other solution (ie 3rd party cloud based tools like drop box or...)

Would luv to get other people's opinions on this subject...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sharing files and source across more than one machine there is always the possibility to loose something when not using some version control. I personally use [git](http://git-scm.com/) (a distributed version control system, actually, just [the stupid content tracker](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/)) for everything, especially for stuff that is *live* on many machines.

The benefits of a *light* and *distributed* version control system are:

- Obviously, the versioning ;)
- Consistency gets checked.
- You retain a history of all your changes.
- You can flexibly branch and merge as you like, w/o running into trouble when having too many parallel trees you sync *manually*.
- You get to know version control, especially, you get to love distributed version control.
- You can literally share a repository with others, who in turn can branch/merge at their own leisure.
- Even when using version control, you are still free to have snapshots lying around *w/o* any version control ;).

So, I am strongly against manually managing synchronization - even in a *one-man-show* of a project.

Comment: thanks, yes must look into git. Where do you keep your remote repository?

Comment: Some stuff is on github, but most of my repos are at home and on some server i have shell access to.